# Why aren't $59$ L tiles the answer to this problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions, tiling

[image]

$$4*(1+3+5+7)=8^2.$$

$4*$(sum of odds from first to $k$th odd number)=area of a square region=$4*k^2$.

$k-1$ is the number of $L$'s.

You can solve the $10\times 12$ problem via considering $10\times 10$ and the extra $1\times 2$ not added via an $L$, one $L$ would be too big. to make the extra is too big.

$14400/4$=total area/area each$=3600,\quad n=60$.

[image] means you use not the 2x2 block as the building block but rather than 64 in^2 block as the building block, a interesting thing is the fnd how many of the 1+3*(4) inch^2 block, how many of the 1+3+5 block, etc.

Comment: I really can't follow your reasoning ... but I do note that 'the extra 1x2' is wrong ... after tiling a square 10x10 you are left with a 10x2, not a 1x2.  Also, it's going to be far more than 60 ... Consider that 2 feet is 3 times 8 inches ... so a 2x2 feet area requires 9 of these squares ... containing 27 L-shaped tiles.  And you'll need a whole bunch of those 2x2 feet areas covered to get up to 10x12

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) that the L-tiles keep getting bigger and bigger. I think that perhaps you just have the 3 different size L-tiles shown in the diagram. So you keep repeating the 8 inch by 8 inch pattern.

Comment: @paw88789 Oh!  So that's how the OP is thinking about it, now I see it! .. but yes, I agree, I think that's not the right interpretation of the problem. I also see the problem as covering the 10x12 feet area using repeated instances of this 8x8 inches pattern

Comment: So the floor is tiled with $15 * 18$ large squares, and each large square has $3$ L-shapes.

Comment: In addition to careful reading of the problem statement, you might need to watch your arithmetic more carefully. Where did $14400$ come from? Ten feet is $120$ inches, twelve feet is $144$ inches, and $120\times144=17280$.

Comment: For non-Anglesaxon people, as we don't know the relation between inches and feet, we can't solve this question :-)